# What are ways for a low-level wizard to mimic divine spells/abilities?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, divine

I had an idea for a necromancer character that masquerades as an exorcist in order to gain access to areas infested with undead without arousing suspicion. What are the ways that an arcane caster can gain access to (or at least mimic sufficiently) the divine spells and abilities that a cleric or other divine caster would be assumed to have?

By low level, I mean things that would be generally available to a character up to level 10 or so. I know the Wish spells can duplicate divine magic, but I'm looking for something a little more "everyday."

So far I have thought of three things that might help:

- Playing the Part: Act as people would expect a cleric to behave, and let them make their own assumptions. Carry around a holy symbol, invoke the name of a deity frequently, things like that.
- Cast spells on both lists: Heavy use of thematically appropriate spells that are available to arcane and divine casters, such as Protection from Evil.
- Invest in bluff: A few points in the bluff skill might help with people whose suspicions are aroused.

Are there any other mechanical ways to do what I'm thinking of? (feats/alternate class abilities, etc.) Third party sources are acceptable if you can point me to the source.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Arcane Disciple** is a good way and only costs one feat.

(Complete Divine, p. 79)

> Choose a deity, and then select a domain available to clerics of that deity. You can learn to cast the spells associated with that domain as arcane spells.

Icing on the cake would be:

**Domain Granted Power**

(Complete Champion, p. 52)

> Choose one cleric domain. If you worship a specific deity, the domain you choose must be one to which your deity grants access. You now can use that domain’s granted power as a cleric does, but you do not gain access to its spells or extra spell slots.

Comment: Your best bet for a domain to choose with this is Healing, since in most worlds, the spells that covers are by far the most likely to blow your cover.

Comment: These are both great. Am I reading correctly that you don't actually have to worship the deity in question? And the prerequisite ranks in Knowledge: Religion are something I should probably be investing in anyway.

Comment: Arcane Disciple requires a deity. Domain Granted Power does not, but you may be resticted (up to DM) to an alignment based domain. With DM's permission you could probably pick alignment based domain spells for Arcane Disciple as well. Talk it over with your DM.

Answer (score 7):

The False Theurgy skill trick (Complete Scoundrel) may be helpful to you, along with the Disguise Undead spell (Spell Compendium).  Additionally, using the Planar Touchstone for the Catalogues of Enlightenment (Planar Handbook) can give you some divine spells and a domain ability.  Some of the domain abilities, such a Deathbound are worth getting for an arcane necromancer in any case.  Other than that, bluff ranks and appropriate window dressing are key.  Some UMD and a cleric wand or staff may also be helpful.  I mean, if you cast Cure Light Wounds, most people are not going to doubt your divine bona fides.